# How to select buckets of aggregation results based on top hit document attribute?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I am trying to get result for following Elasticsearch query. I got the response as shown below. Now I want to select the buckets based on the top hit document field "source".

```
POST /data/_search?size=0{ 
   "aggs":{ 
      "by_partyIds":{ 
         "terms":{ 
            "field":"id.keyword"
         },
         "aggs":{ 
            "oldest_record":{ 
               "top_hits":{ 
                  "sort":[ 
                     { 
                        "createdate.keyword":{ 
                           "order":"asc"
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  "_source":[ 
                     "source"
                  ],
                  "size":1
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Response :

```
{
              "aggregations": {
                "by_partyIds": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "key": "1",
                      "doc_count": 3,
                      "oldest_record": {
                        "hits": {
                          "total": 3,
                          "max_score": null,
                          "hits": [
                            {
                              "_index": "data",
                              "_type": "osr",
                              "_id": "DcagSm4B9WnM0Ke-MgGk",
                              "_score": null,
                              "_source": {
                                "source": "US"
                              },
                              "sort": [
                                "20-09-18 05:45:26.000000000AM"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "2",
                      "doc_count": 3,
                      "oldest_record": {
                        "hits": {
                          "total": 3,
                          "max_score": null,
                          "hits": [
                            {
                              "_index": "data",
                              "_type": "osr",
                              "_id": "7caiSm4B9WnM0Ke-HwGx",
                              "_score": null,
                              "_source": {
                                "source": "UK"
                              },
                              "sort": [
                                "22-09-18 05:45:26.000000000AM"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
```

Now I want to get the buckets with count US as source. Can we write the query for that? I tried A bucket aggregation which is parent pipeline aggregation which executes a script which determines whether the current bucket will be retained in the parent multi-bucket aggregation. The specified metric must be numeric and the script must return a boolean value. If the script language is expression then a numeric return value is permitted. In this case 0.0 will be evaluated as false and all other values will evaluate to true.

Comment: Elaborate on this: `get the buckets with count US as source` -- do you want to count the records having source value as US?

Comment: I need just bucket counts. For example if I pass parameter as "US" to the query the result would be 1 or if I pass parameter as "UK" the result would be 1 in this current scenario.

Comment: It does not really make sense because you set the size as 1 and order by created date, so the count is always 1.